# Update Progress on processing after fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, progressdialog

I have a webform with two upload controls and a number of textfields. 
When the button is pressed the files get uploaded and then get processed.
The upload takes no time, but the processing does.
I know I can't have an upload control in an update panel, so I can't work out how to use the update progress control to show my progress.

My page with an updateprogress control that does work is as follows:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DynamicLayout="true">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="LOADING">
                    Your data is being processed<br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="/images/loading.gif" /><br />
                    <br />
                    Please wait...
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <div class="addFixture">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ValidationGroup="fixture" runat="server" />
            <label>
                Type
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <label>
                    Date
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>
                    Name 1</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <label>
                    Name 2
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <label>
                        First XML File</label>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="firstFileUp" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Second Xml File</label>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="secondFileUp" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton"  runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
                    <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessageLabel" runat="server" EnableTheming="false"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have searched for this, but people seem to be trying to get the progress of the file upload and not the processing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the UpdatePanel as all the way you can't use FileUpload controls inside it.
Add to the SubmitButton OnClientClick property with following value: `OnClientClick="showProgress()"`
Also add onto the page javascript function below:

```
function showProgress() {
     var updateProgress = $get("<%= UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>");
     updateProgress.style.display = "block";
}
```

By the way, consider to use some async file upload control like one from the Ajax Control Toolkit library

Comment: I had thought of this, but the button also does validation (I deleted my validators off the example to shorten it a bit). How would this work with validation?

Comment: I used something simialr to this, but checked if the page was valid first:   if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                Page_ClientValidate();
            }

            if (Page_IsValid) {

                document.getElementById("ProgressArea").style.display = "block";


            }

Comment: You can use the file upload control in an update panel. In the page load, add the following statements - Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnUpload); - however this does not help you much with the processing progress problem (which I am also having).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use an UpdatePanel and the FileUpload if you use the [ASyncFileUploadControl](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx). It works pretty well. Make sure you download the latest version because there were a couple of issues with prior releases.

Comment: does this upload it immediately though or can I do it on the button click?