# TextBox won't update

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

I have a textbox within a update panel in a aspx page

and here's my code:

scene 1:

```
protected void UploadPromoFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = "Starting upload...";
        //UpdatePanel.Update();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlTagTextBox.Text))
        {
            var Movie = Vitagamer.Movies.DB.DBUtilities.Get.ByUrlTag(UrlTagTextBox.Text);
            //Movie.UploadPromo();
        }
        else
        {
            //Vitagamer.Movies.PromotionHelper.Youtube.Execute.UploadAllPromoVideos();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = "Files were uploaded successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = Ex.Message;
    }
}
```

scene two:

```
protected void UploadPromoFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = "Starting upload...";
        UpdatePanel.Update();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlTagTextBox.Text))
        {
            var Movie = Vitagamer.Movies.DB.DBUtilities.Get.ByUrlTag(UrlTagTextBox.Text);
            //Movie.UploadPromo();
        }
        else
        {
            //Vitagamer.Movies.PromotionHelper.Youtube.Execute.UploadAllPromoVideos();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = "Files were uploaded successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = Ex.Message;
    }
}
```

in both cases, i never seee that starting upload text but i see the files were uploaded successfully text.

how to let the user know that the uploading is starting since it may take a while. i can't use a progress bar since i'm using youtube api and it uses sync. upload. i don't need the progress bar, i just wanna view a text to know the user that upload has started. how to do it? thank u.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just interested in letting the USER *know* a file is being uploaded: Here is a way to do it without needing to write too much special Client *OR* Server code *per-se*.

Since you already have an *UpdatePanel*, you now just need to add an **`UpdateProgress`** with a nice *image* and *caption*:

### **ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadPromoFilesButton" 
                                  EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

        <!--  YOUR FILE UPLOAD ASPX GOES HERE -->

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">       
    <ProgressTemplate>         
        <center>
            <img src="../Content/img/CircularProgressAnimation.gif" />
            <br /><i>Uploading file, please wait....</i> 
        </center>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

You can also look at [**`this`**](http://www.learningpenguin.net/myblog/2012/07/19/simulate-updateprogress-when-using-asp-net-fileupload-control/) and [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585140/update-progress-on-processing-after-fileupload) as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't instantly update the panel. The entire method executes, then you see the successfully uploaded message because that was the last thing you set the text to.

To see this in action, try removing this line:

```
YoutubeStatusLabel.Text = "Files were uploaded successfully.";
```

However, then it'll say "starting upload" AFTER it's done. That's no good! So use client side script to set the "Starting upload..." text.

Comment: isn't there a way to get it done on the server side?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: don't do things on the server side that should be done on the client side. But if you really want to go there, then yes, there is. Learn AJAX and build a server side message queue. Have AJAX (or even better, try [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)) obtain the messages and then display them. And if you want to display them in a nice format, use a notification library such as [Noty](http://ned.im/noty/). If you decide the AJAX route, I recommend using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't seeing the text is because you never send information back to the user.

Essentially, the process is like this:

- Your request comes in to the server
- The server process the request and creates all of the HTML text (at this point the method has completely run, so the `YoutubeStatusLabel.Text` will be the last thing it was set to in your `UploadPromoFilesButton_Click` method)
- The HTML text is sent back to the client

If you want to show the intermediate text, you need to either set the value on the client side (JavaScript) or do multiple post backs to the server.  The last option would also require JavaScript.

I would look into SignalR for more advanced Client Server communication.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see the first update to `YoutubeStatusLabel.Text` as your code is executing on the server and has not been returned to the browser yet.

It would be worth reading up on the [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf922ts9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I don't see the benefit of notifying the user that the upload has started and then again after 5 seconds. I would set the text to `Starting upload...` and then had a callback which updated the label to `Files were uploaded successfully.` once the process is complete. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)